# Convert XML to JSON in C language

Tags: c, xml, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON <-> XML in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395072/json-xml-in-c-c)

Is there a C function or a simple C library to convert XML to JSON?

For example, I would like the function to be able to convert the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reqTransDetails>
        <token>6xPVIl83hgyhtwZ/y0azu9MwMCQVSIVj/qM=</token>
        <ordering>desc</ordering>
        <status>A</status>
        <blockSize>999</blockSize>
    <blockNo>0</blockNo>
</reqTransDetails>
```

To:

```
{
  "reqTransDetails": {
    "token": "6xPVIl83hgyhtwZ/y0azu9MwMCQVSIVj/qM=",
    "ordering": "desc",
    "status": "A",
    "blockSize": "999",
    "blockNo": "0"
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh wow. Why do you want to do this in C?

Comment: Because I'm using HP Loadrunner which uses C as its scripting language.

Comment: Maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395072/json-xml-in-c-c

Comment: This is a dupe, yes. And here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7396799/694576