# XSLT into C++ to get JSON from XML

Tags: c++, xml, json, xslt

I've been trying to find out how to convert an xml entry into json in C++. I came across this topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7396799/694576

In this answer it talks about using an **xslt** to convert it. Which I found a type of repository here:

https://github.com/doekman/xml2json-xslt

My question is, I've never heard of XSLT and can't get my head around how I can use it within my c++ project to convert XML into json. Could anyone shed some light and help me on my way?

Comment: To be honest, I do not really know an answer to your question, but perhaps this link may help you https://xalan.apache.org/old/xalan-c/overview.html. At least from the page content, it sounds as it may be helpful ("Xalan is an XSLT processor for transforming XML documents into HTML, text, or other XML document types.").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xml2json](https://github.com/Cheedoong/xml2json) is a header-only c++ library. It has some tests and may be helpful.

**Edit**

If XSLT is a must, please try [xalan-c](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/)'s [XalanTransformer C++ API](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/usagepatterns.html#xalantransformer). There is a sample(and detailed explanation): [XalanTransform](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/samples.html#xalantransform).

> You can run XalanTransform from the XalanTransform subdirectory with
>
> `XalanTransform foo.xml foo.xsl foo.out`

A sample xml2json.xsl file can be obtained from [here](http://www.bjelic.net/2012/08/01/coding/convert-xml-to-json-using-xslt/) and [here](https://github.com/bojanbjelic/xml2json/). Replace the above foo.xsl with this one and see the outputs.

Hope this will help.